# Should Windows 10 Pro have a GUI option for "Allow wake timers" under Sleep in a power plan's "Advanced settings"?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, power-management, wake-up

There are many examples of Windows 10 instructions that assume that the **Sleep** setting within the "Advanced settings" for a power plan will have an entry called "**Allow wake timers**".  Here is [one example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162958/how-to-disable-wake-timer).  Here is [another example that includes an image](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/63070-enable-disable-wake-timers-windows-10-a.html).

I have Windows 10 Pro, which I would have assumed should at least have the features of Windows 10.  Yet, while I have Sleep options for "Sleep after" and "Hibernate after", those are the only visible options.  There is no entry under Sleep for "Allow wake timers".

(Side observation: The only four "Advanced settings" entries under each power plan are

- "Desktop background settings",
- "Sleep",
- "Display", and
- "Battery".

Unlike the image in the second link above, I don't see any "Wireless Adapter Settings", "USB Settings", "Power buttons and ...", or anything else in the image of the second example page above.  So there are other observable differences besides the one about "Allow wake timers".)

Should Windows 10 Pro have a visible "Allow wake timers" GUI option as well, similar to what many expect for Windows 10?

If so, is that option simply hidden with the possibility of showing it?  Or is it moved to some other location in the GUI interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible fix the problem of the missing "Allow wake timers" is
described in the article
[How to Add or Remove "Allow wake timers" from Power Options in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65716-add-remove-allow-wake-timers-power-options-windows-10-a.html).

The article suggests to enable this option by running the
Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and entering the following command:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\BD3B718A-0680-4D9D-8AB2-E1D2B4AC806D /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

To undo the above, run the following command :

```
powercfg -attributes SUB_SLEEP BD3B718A-0680-4D9D-8AB2-E1D2B4AC806D +ATTRIB_HIDE
```

If this doesn't help, check if your BIOS has some Power/Sleep State
settings, and try to switch them. For example, in
[this post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Tablet-and/Allow-Wake-Timers-not-available/m-p/4464185)
the setting for a Lenovo computer needed to be set to "Linux" and not
"Windows", as was the default.